# How to get Thumbnail in facebook status?

Tags: facebook

No Thumbnail in facebook status when i share my website url...

Please help...

Screen Shot:- https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7O6g.png

header meta code

```
<head>
<title><?= NAME_PAGE ?> SITE NAME</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/frontend/css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/frontend/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/frontend/css/animate.css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/frontend/images/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<meta property=”og:image” content=”http://SITENAME.com/frontend/images/logo.png”>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook (and other social networks) will pick the first image on the page you share so if you don't have an image on the page add

link rel="image_src"  href =""

to the head section of your website.

Comment: Can you give me a link to the site?